# What is the best way to add alpha numeric filtering to a C# dataset?

Tags: c#, dataset

We have a section of code that loads a text file into a data table, and we use the DataTable's select statement to hand it a filter statement and a sort statement:

```
DataRow[] dataRowArray = table.Select(filterText, sortExp);
```

This is all loaded as strings since we are pulling it from a file.  The issue we are having is that when the user sorts something that is a numeric column, they will get the string sort: 1, 11, 12 .... 2, 20, 21 ... 3, 30, 31 etc.  It also impacts the filtering because things like `<= 10` will only return 1 and not 2, 3, etc.

What I have done to start is write a custom `IComparable` type I called `AlphaNumericString`.  Now when the sort runs, it uses that `compareTo` method and everything works great.  But I'm not quite clear on how to get the DataSet filter to play nice with this.

**Mostly I am getting errors like:**

```
Cannot perform '=' operation on DataAccess.Source.AlphaNumericString and System.String
```

I have tried overloading the operands, but they never seem to get used:

```
public static bool operator <=(AlphaNumericString alpha, object val)
{
    // Compare them
}
```

Could anyone offer suggestions on how I might go about overriding the filter logic?

Comment: What is the type of `table`? Is it `IEnumerable<string>`?

Comment: It is created as DataTable newTable = new DataTable(), so unless that happens implicitly I would say not.